# Google sheet script, return range value is 3 cells off

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote this code with a trigger to send me emails upon a specific number of days remaining in the schedule. Everything works fine, but the content of my email is always 3 rows off for the variables `fournir` and `projet`. I think that it's probably because of the `getRange` associated with these variables but since I'm fairly new with scripting, I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance

```
function checkValue()
{
var NOMBREDELIGNES = 3000;
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange(3, 8, NOMBREDELIGNES); // ligne de départ,   colonne, nombre de lignes
var values = range.getValues();

for (var row in values) {
for (var col in values[row]) {
  var crissedevaleur = values[row][col];
  if(crissedevaleur == 1 || crissedevaleur == 3 || crissedevaleur == 7)     {
    var projet = sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue(); 
    var fournir = sheet.getRange(row,4).getValue();  
    MailApp.sendEmail("dufourlarouche@gotoast.ca","Rappel de votre  compte en banque [" + projet + "]" ,"Échéance dans " + crissedevaleur + " jours pour \n\n" + fournir);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include in your question an example showing what you expect to get and what you are currently getting? See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: With this function I expect to get an email for each "crissedevaleur" value found in column 8. In that email, I'd like to receive information regarding the information associated to the value which is found on the same row in column 1 and 4 aka "var Projet" and "var fournir"

Answer (score 0):

When you use range.getValues() in Google Apps Script, you get a double array. When you loop through the array the rows start at 0 and count up.

The row value corresponds to the row in the array, not the row on your sheet. To fix this, you will need to simply add range.getRow() or 3 to the row you are getting the value of.

Use:

```
var projet = sheet.getRange(row+range.getRow(),1).getValue(); 
var fournir = sheet.getRange(row+range.getRow(),4).getValue();
```

or

```
var projet = sheet.getRange(row+3,1).getValue(); 
var fournir = sheet.getRange(row+3,4).getValue();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It still isn't working. Here is what it does. Let's say it found a value on the 2nd row (row 5 since it started at 3). It adds 2+3 and returns the value on row 23, column 1 and row 23, column 4

Comment: found the solution! Thanks for your help!